# Using event field as hash variable

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, logstash, influxdb

I'm receving events in Logstash containing measurement, values and tags. I do not know ahead of time what field there are and what tags. So i wanted to do something like this:

```
input {
   http {}
}

filter {
  ruby {
    code => '
      tags = event.get("stats_tags").split(",")
      samples = event.get("stats_samples").split(" ")

      datapoints = {}

      samples.each {|s|
        splat = s.split(" ")
        datapoints[splat[0]] = splat[1]
      }

      event.set("[@metadata][stats-send-as-tags]", tags)
      event.set("[@metadata][stats-datapoints]", datapoints)

    '
  }
}

output {
    influxdb {
        host => "influxdb"
        db => "events_db"        
        measurement => measurement
        send_as_tags => [@metadata][stats-send-as-tags]
        data_points => [@metadata][stats-datapoints]
    }
}
```

But this produce error. After much googling to no avail i'm starting to think this is imposible.

Is there a way to pass hash and array from event field to output/filter configuration?

EDIT: If i doublequote it, the error i'm getting is

```
  output {
    influxdb {
      # This setting must be a hash
      # This field must contain an even number of items, got 1
      data_points => "[@metadata][stats-datapoints]"
      ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: are you missing quotes on the influxdb output... ie `"[@metadata][stats-send-as-tags]"`

Comment: In double quotes i'm getting "This setting must be a hash",  "This field must contain an even number of items, got 1". From this i've got the premise for the question

Comment: Hello @RawCode, did you get anywhere with this? I've got an identical issue [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/howto-parse-json-into-hash/84474) and I'm running out of ideas ;)

Comment: @Niko Nope. I've decided to move all this logic to fluentd, and to custom streaming processing in the future

Comment: Cool, thanks for your response. Also, if you follow the thread I linked [above](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/howto-parse-json-into-hash/84474) to the bottom, you will find that magnusbaeck (Logstash Plugins Community Maintainer) and I reach the conclusion that a hash is not dereferenced by the output plugin.